# maven assembly descriptor- copy folder and files of any level

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using maven-assembly-plugin to build a tar.gz file. I want content of a folder and all subfolders to be included in the tar file. Can anyone help in this? Thanks in advance. :)

Here is my assembly.xml content:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
<id>dist</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/dist/lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*</include>
        </includes>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

I have two directories under /src/main/dist/lib and need all the content of these two directories to be copied inside my tar file. 
With above assembly.xml, only first level folder are copied with no content under them.

e.g. If I have folders like : /src/main/dist/lib/folder1/... and /src/main/dist/lib/folder1/...
Generated tar just have lib/folder1 and lib/folder2 with no files and subfolders under it.

Comment: please add your pom.xml in question @user2802446

Answer (score 3):

Use the syntax: `

> ```
> <includes>
>   <include>**</include>
> </includes>
> ```

`